# Does Intention-to-Treat reduce bias in a non-randomised trial?

Tags: clinical-trials

I am involved in a trial comparing the withdrawal patients staying in an in-patient unit experience after discontinuing either of two drugs. **The drug they were taking before they commenced abstinence will not be not randomised**.

A reviewer on the ethics committee who are assessing the study enquired about whether we were following intention-to-treat principles.

I never even considered using intention to treat since:

(i) participants cannot switch drugs during treatment since they are only being measured after they have stopped
(ii) participants were not randomised, the decision to use either drug was based on the preferences of the prescribing doctor and the participant.

But just say participants decide the withdrawal they experience is too intense and want to resume use of either the drug they were originally on or the other drug. If they agree to continue providing withdrawal symptom data **should their withdrawal symptom data still be analysed as if they had never resumed use of the drug?**

From what I understand from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5654877/pdf/wjem-18-1075.pdf) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364269/does-intention-to-treat-apply-to-the-cases-that-should-have-been-excluded-but-no) intention to treat preserves the bias-removal effect inherent in randomisation.

But **does intention to treat offer the same advantages when there is no randomisation?**

As you can tell I am a bit confused and would welcome some clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think intention-to-treat should be considered in non-randomly assigned groups. Just thinking about a study of a programme to change behaviour (smoking). Group A nominated themselves for the programme, but 40 out of 50 of them did not complete it, it was sooo boring. It would be unfair to compare the 10 who did complete with the comparison group. The Intention-to-Treat principle is important because drop-outs skew your data, and if your intervention/drug is to be assessed comprehensively surely you need findings that account for the likelihood that people don't finish the intervention/drug prescription.

Comment: PS i would have to disagree with Jiwei on the problems with your non random assignment. You analyse the results in the same way as you  do an RCT, results just come with the caveat - there may be a diff between these 2 groups. But your study surely adds insight, despite this

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gale. Just trying to think this through: What if in your example the outcome measure was nicotine withdrawal during abstinence? Would you include the 40/50 people who resumed smoking in Group A's withdrawal data *after* they had resumed smoking for the remainder of the trial, assuming they continue to provide withdrawal data? If only 10 participants in Group B relapsed then an intention to treat analysis would conclude that Group A's intervention was associated with less severe withdrawal than Group B despite the fact that more people in Group A had relapsed...

Comment: Jesus llewmills your a brain-melter! Let me try and get my head round that

Comment: ...Surely in this scenario including data after resumption of smoking would introduce more bias than a per-protocol analysis? I hasten to add I am not trying to say your suggestion was foolish or wrong. Far from it: I really appreciate the help. I am just trying to think it through.

Comment: Well i'm not sure i have the brain power you need here llewmills. How is nicotine withdrawal reported?

Comment: Intention-to-Treat melts my brain. Nicotine withdrawal reported on a 0-10 scale or something like that.

Comment: you see you are throwing me with this relapse business, and the scale. If you keep the outcome as dichotomous, either they gave up the fags or they didn't. Yes you do need the data from all study participants who were there at the start of the study. If you dont have it you need account for missing data - i cant remember the techniques used to do this, but there are techniques i know from working on a cochrane review which looked for these. I guess if you are missing too much data, due to drop outs, the study is ruined.

Comment: sorry! Yes it is an idiosyncratic paradigm for sure. Yet more evidence that intention-to-treat is not a one-size-fits-all approach. I think for a longitudinal analysis a mixed-effects model does a type of ersatz data imputation that would more-or-less follow intention-to-treat principles without needing to include data that violates the assumptions of the study. We're doing a survival analysis as well (time to failure of abstinence) but the primary outcome is withdrawal - measured on various continuous scales - during abstinence. So I need to think about ITT for these.

Comment: i should add, that in this scenario drop-outs could be counted as zeros when you are counting up how many participants actually quit smoking, as long as that is in your study protocol i cant see anyone arguing against that ... or maybe they dropped out because they had succeeded ... i give up!

Comment: i guess intention-to-treat is important when drop-outs are a type of failure for your drug/intervention - there's a paper in this!

Comment: Yes I think so. There are certainly a lot already out there but it would be fun to try to come up with experimental scenarios where ITT actually *introduces* bias.

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen the term "intent to treat" in randomized trials, where you are analyzing the effect of treatment assignment. Not sure if it is the right term to use in this case.
As for the ethical issues, perhaps they are worried these patients do not voluntarily discontinue?

Comparing the withdrawal patients from two different drugs in non-randomized setting sounds a very complicated analysis to me. You need to make sure the two groups are comparable in the first place after controlling for the confounding factors. Otherwise the results are difficult to interpret. Not sure if it is feasible in this case. Even if the two groups of patients are from a randomized trial for two drugs, the withdrawal patients are not comparable.

Should their withdrawal symptom data still be analysed as if they had never resumed use of the drug? Yes, I think so. If you are interested in the withdrawal symptoms, the data after resumed use of the drug may not be useful. Perhaps you can also do a time to failure analysis and consider the resumed use as a failure. That being said, I am not sure how to design this analysis properly in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Jiwei He. The best we can get is some attempt at matching participants based on age, gender etc. It will be a pilot study whose main objective is to *describe* withdrawal from the two different drugs. Sample size will be too low for between-group inferences to have much meaning. Nevertheless longitudinal quantitative analysis will be done using repeated measurement of continuous withdrawal scales, so I need to think about ITT. We will most certainly be doing a survival analysis where failure of abstinence is the event, but this is not the primary quantitative analysis

Comment: Sorry, I probably misread the question. I thought the question is asking about two groups of patients taking two different drugs respectively. If the group of patients were taking both drugs and discontinuing from either one of them, it makes sense to do a comparison between the two withdrawal groups, if you can do a good matching at the time of withdrawal (e.g. using PS related method). Perhaps patients who do poorly more intend to discontinue drug A versus drug B. Perhaps you should take into such factors into consideration. not just the baseline factors like age and gender.

Comment: No you are right that it is two groups of patients. Each patient takes only one drug or the other, not both. And which drug is not randomised. It is mainly a pilot study whose findings may justify applying for funding to run a well-powered and randomised design.

Comment: I see. If that is the case, I do think analysis within each group makes more sense. Patients taking drug A versus drug B are two different groups with no overlapping. Not sure if this difference can be resolved by matching.

Comment: I take your point @Jiwei He, however, the fact that it is quasi-experimental rather than experimental research does not prevent running statistical models and estimating effects, but does prevent one from drawing any strong conclusions about causation.